# How can I block a certain website using hosts file even if I'm connected to a VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, browser, localhost, blocking

In order to block some certain sites, I use the following codes in my hosts file:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1 http://www.hamdardi.net/
```

But that works only when I'm not connected to a VPN.
How can I block a certain website **using hosts file** even if I'm connected to a VPN?
please avoid suggestions like `leechblock for firefox`, `stayfocused for google chrome`. I want a solution that works for all browsers installed on my computer (IE, firefox, google chrome) that doesn't let me to access and edit the blocking settings while the sites are blocked.
I have tried a lot of ways like `localfilter`, `BinarySwitch Eclipse`, etc. But I've always found a way to sneak out.
This time I wanna block the sites using `hosts file` and then set a random password on the file for the administrator of the computer (not the SYSTEM) and give this password to someone else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hosts file should always work - VPN or not. Drop the http protocol. These entries should be sufficient:

> 127.0.0.1 www.hamdardi.net
>
> 127.0.0.1 hamdardi.net

Edit: Useful debugging guide: https://serverfault.com/a/452269

Comment: Marek Rost is right. Your mistake is that you have written "`http://www.hamdardi.net/`". HOSTS file only accepts fully qualified domain names, not URLs.

Comment: @FleetCommand but the solution didn't work. I've shared [my hosts file content here for you](https://goo.gl/kvDLM0)

Comment: @sepideh as FleetCommander said only FQDNs = fully qualified domain names can be used. You have several errors in the file. As a result your entries are completly ignored. No ports or mapping ip address to ip address is allowed. Same with wildcards, so this line won't work as well: `127.0.0.1 CRL.VERISIGN.NET.*`

Comment: @sepideh hopefully this will help you: https://nopaste.me/view/49d8ffa7

Comment: @MarekRost that worked, thanks. so you mean the wrong lines on the hosts file caused the windows to ignore the hostst completely? The content of my hosts file is now as [the following](https://nopaste.me/view/1076fa19)

Comment: @MarekRost as the last question: **www.hamdardi.net** was blocked when I was using the [the wrong hosts file](https://nopaste.me/view/49d8ffa7) **without VPN** so it was not totally ignored? am I wrong? so what was the main problem?

Comment: From what i found: it varies case to case - sometimes, when there is error in syntax, it is ignored completly. Another time rules are applied from start of file until the first mistake. This is why i posted that debuggin link into the answer - so you can test it out and see if changes in the file were applied.

Comment: problem again. My main purpose was to block the [area51 site](area51.stackexchange.com) so [I've added two lines to the end of the file](https://nopaste.me/view/9e6ca7ac). But again **that works without vpn** but **doesn't work with vpn**

Comment: hmm... your local DNS cache could override the hosts rule. Try flushing your DNS cache. I think the command is `ipconfig /flushdns`