# How can I block a certain website using url filter capability of my router even if I'm connected to a VPN?

Tags: networking, router, vpn, blocking

In another attempt to reach the goal that I had [in the following question](https://superuser.com/questions/1106795/how-can-i-block-a-certain-website-using-hosts-file-even-if-im-connected-to-a-vp), how can I block a certain website using hosts file even if I’m connected to a VPN?

I tried to enable url filter capability of my `ASUS Wireless Router`:

[image]

But that also does only work when I’m not connected to a VPN. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:** That's impossible

**Long answer:** The purpose of VPN is to create an end-to-end connection in which the contents of the connection is encrypted and inaccessible to the outside world, hence a virtually private connection. Now you want to defeat the very purpose of this type of networking and peek inside the VPN? Well, you can't; at least you need a supercomputer instead of router, with the ability to break the encryption. You can only filter the connection at its endpoints, i.e. either before the request goes through VPN or after it comes out of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connected to a VPN outside of your network and you want to filter out websites, you need to place your router in the middle:

Your computer - Your router - VPN Server

Otherwise your router will only see data garbage and will not be able to filter out anything.

EDIT:

To understand what a VPN does, look at the following:

Without a VPN a normal connection looks like this (simplified)

1. You (your computer) requests content from www.website.com
2. Your router forwards a request from your internal IP to www.website.com
3. www.website.com sends the requested data back to your router
4. Your router sends the data to your internal IP

If you would want to block websites, your router would be able to block www.website.com because the router is able to deny or allow connections to www.website.com because the router is able to see where the connection is coming from and where it is supposed to go.

With a VPN however:

1. Your computer connects to the VPN and encrypts the whole connection
2. Your computer send an encrypted request to the VPN Server
3. Your router forwards a request from your internal IP to the VPN Server.
   The router does not know where you really want to go as the router can only see the VPN-Server in the initial request

If you would want to block certain websites you would need the router in the same network as otherwise the router would only see encrypted data.

Comment: Please rephrase it?  If the router wasn't in the middle, it wouldn't see anything at all since the data won't get routed through it...

Comment: so you mean it's not possible for someone like me who is using softwares like `Cyberghost`? My computer connects with the vpn server through my router and then that vpn server connects me to the world. so I have the configuration `My computer---My router---vpn server`

Comment: What he means is that data gets encrypted on your computer. Thus the router cannot know you're requesting that domain. You could block it only if the router was client on the VPN and not your computer.

Comment: @MarekRost so you mean blocking should be done before the browser sends data to vpn tunnel to encrypt it. so that can only be done through blocking in browser-level `ie, leechblock,etc`. what about the hosts file? that is my another question. it is impossible for it, too?....I mean does hosts file check the outgoing packs after being encrypted by vpn or before? In fact what's the purpose of hosts file in windows then?

Comment: Exactly - browser or the hosts file. Check the other question.

Comment: Thats a good question. I think that depends on the VPN software. Try it out. The hosts file is used to map IPs to hostnames. Open the hosts file, and add another line: google.com 127.0.0.1

Comment: @sepideh To fully answer you is beyond character limit of comment. Also you're mixing two things - domain to ip resolution and blocking requests when you already have the domain ip found out. Use the hosts file.