# How to block distracting websites using hosts file?

Tags: networking, vpn, blocking, hosts-file, selfcontrol

Regarding [the question](https://superuser.com/questions/1106795/how-can-i-block-a-certain-website-using-hosts-file-even-if-im-connected-to-a-vp), I've asked before and the feedback I received, I've done the following in order to block `Twitter`

1. I ran `command prompt` as administrator and I entered the code `ipconfig /flushdns`

[image]

2. I wrote the following code lines at the end of the hosts file:

> 127.0.0.1 www.twitter.com
>
> 127.0.0.1 twitter.com

[image]

But seems that it won't work and I'm able to access `twitter`

**P.S:** I'm using [psiphon](https://psiphon3.com/en/index.html) and other VPNs to access the web

Comment: Remember that browsers often cache DNS resolution... you may need to restart the browser, wipe the browser cache, or even reboot, for the changes in hosts to take effect even after flushing the DNS cache of Windows.

Comment: @acejavelin that doesn't make any difference. I did

Comment: Does it work if you disable the VPN?

Comment: @acejavelin yes

Answer (score 1):

Using a VPN basically bypasses the hosts file completely. Since all the traffic is encrypted, Windows doesn't know if you access Twitter. Check your VPN software for a blocking option.

Comment: Even with a VPN your computer still does DNS lookups... And it still uses the host file and DNS entries, it just does the lookups via the VPN connection depending on the configuration. I don't believe that this answer is correct.

Comment: @acejavelin You are correct about VPNs and hosts files - but looking at psiphon it appears to be a proxy as well, meaning the request is shuttled off to the proxy and host is resolved there, bypassing the hosts file.